# I installed .NET Framework 4.5, but when I change version there is no this version

Tags: windows, iis, .net-framework

I have installed the .NET Framework 4.5.1, you can see this:

[image]

but I can not change IIS .NET Framework version, why?
[image: 4.5]

there only list v2.0 and v4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal, version 4.5 of the .NET framework is built on the existing [.NET 4.0 CLR (Common Language Runtime)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) and therefore does not need a separate option in the IIS application pool settings.

Depending on what kind of application you are hosting in IIS you just need to make sure it is built against the correct version of .NET and your web.config is configured correctly.